# How can i find these containers on photo by opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

there's an image

[image: image with containers]

it's my code

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('Photos\\1photo.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel_size = 5
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (kernel_size, kernel_size), 0)

sharp_strength = 9.1
sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                           [-1, sharp_strength, -1],
                           [-1, -1, -1]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(gray, -1, sharpen_kernel)
cv2.imshow('sharpen', sharpen)
cv2.waitKey()

threshold = 140
max_value = 280
thresh = cv2.threshold(sharpen, threshold, max_value, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)
cv2.imshow("ThreshInv", thresh)
cv2.waitKey()

kernel_size = 3
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_size, kernel_size))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow("Close", closing)
cv2.waitKey()

#

cnts = cv2.findContours(closing, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

min_area = 80
max_area = 150
image_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if min_area < area < max_area:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36, 255, 12), 2)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

After blur, thresh, inversion and morph, i have image like this

[image: c]

Carriages and containers are quite visible, but findContours can't detect them.
Can i fix this?

Comment: I doubt those containers can be enhanced with low level methods. you might need a neural network for this. "instance segmentation".

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I'm new at neural networks, can you please recommend me some channels to learn or libs that i can use?